# Why is scale animation affected by translate property?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mmwtmy), the **scale** animation is not working when I use `translate` property initially inside `transform`:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

import './style.css';
const fadeInAndScale = keyframes`
  to {
    transform: scale(3);
   }
`;
let FadeInCircleStyled = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(0); // if translate is not here scale animation works
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  animation: ${fadeInAndScale} 2.5s ease-out;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FadeInCircleStyled />
    </div>
  );
}
```

if I **remove** `translate(50%, 50%)` from `transform` it works. Why?

Comment: This does look like a quirk (?bug?) as, at least on my Chrome(Edge)/Windows 10 I can go right down to 0.000000000000000001 for the initial scale and it all transforms OK. But with scale 0 it does no gradual transitioning - just jumps to the final value at the end of the animation - is that what you are seeing? I can't understand why since the translating by 50% should not be affected by the scaling.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava scale works fine when translate is present as long as the scale doesn't start from exactly 0.

Answer (score 0):

This transform here is overwriting the other transform.

```js
const fadeInAndScale = keyframes`
  to {
    transform: scale(3);
  }
`;
```

You have to arrange transforms so that the persistent one is always included in the ones that could override it, like this:

```js
const fadeInAndScale = keyframes`
  to {
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(3); // <-- now the translate will remain
   }
`;

let FadeInCircleStyled = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(0);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  animation: ${fadeInAndScale} 2.5s ease-out;
`;
```

Personally, I'd just strip the transform from the styled component and let the animation handle it all:

```js
const fadeInAndScale = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(3);
  }
`;

let FadeInCircleStyled = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  animation: ${fadeInAndScale} 2.5s ease-out;
`;
```

Note that Styled Components can also handle SASS. So this more natural version will also work:

```js
let FadeInCircleStyled = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;

  @keyframes fadeInAndScale {
    from { transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(0); }
    to { transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(3); }
  }

  animation: ${fadeInAndScale} 2.5s ease-out;
`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because transform translate is not present in the initial css if is not present the animation won't work. If still is not working try using position

add

```
const fadeInAndScale = keyframes` to
```

{ transform: translate(1%, 1%) scale(3); } `;

Comment: unclear answer, translate *is* present in the initial css. Also why is scale not working?

Comment: const fadeInAndScale = keyframes`
  to {
    transform: translate(10%, 10%) scale(3);
   }
`;

Comment: i mean is not present on your const *you only have scale(3)*

Comment: question was why is *scale* not working?

Comment: Animation is also asking to translate, finds nothing then it won't show anything